# List(of myclass) initializer vb.net

Tags: .net, initializer

I have a class like this

```
Class Myclass
  itemdata as string
  name as string
End Class
```

how do i initialised this class with and array of string for both properties?

this is what i am trying, which os obviously wrong

```
Dim ls As New List(Of Myclass)(New Myclass() {("A1,A2,A3,A4".Split(","))})
```

I need something like this after initialization, the value of each item in the list will be like as if assigned manually like this

```
List(0).itemdata="A1"
List(0).name="A1"
List(1).itemdata="A2"
List(2).name="A2"
```

etc

Comment: You really need a [mcve]. What is `dicOpts`? Where does `key` come from?

Comment: pls check the edits

Comment: How are you expecting the four values to get inserted into a class with two fields? Are you expecting two classes or four classes created?

Comment: pls check the edits

Comment: I think you need to check your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with `Myclass` is a reserved name, so I've used `Myclass2`.

This is the closest to you code that I can make it:

```
Dim dicOpts = New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"foo", "bar,woo"}}
Dim key = "foo"
Dim ls As New List(Of Myclass2) From { New Myclass2() With { .itemdata = dicOpts(key).Split(","c)(0), .name = dicOpts(key).Split(","c)(1) } }
```

That gives:

[image: result]

---

Based on your edits I think this is closer to what you want:

```
Dim text = "A1,A2,A3,A4"
Dim ls = _
    text _
        .Split(","c) _
        .Select(Function (x) New Myclass2() With { .itemdata = x, .name = x }) _
        .ToList()
```

I now get this:

[image: result2]

Comment: It seems the linq statement is not correct, it underlined the `From` till the end, saying expected end of statement

Comment: @Smith - There is no LINQ code here at all. I tested the code before posting. It's valid VB.NET code.

Comment: I am using vs2008, so maybe there might be a compiler difference?

Comment: @Smith - Yes, that may be true. And you should mention that in the question. I'm using the latest LINQPad to run the code.

Answer (score -1):

i've renamed your class(es)....hope u understand what u mean with it:

Create your Class:

```
Class xxx '(this was your 'myclass')
    Private _p1 As String
    Private _p2 As String
    Private _p3 as String

    Sub New(p1 As String, p2 As String)
        ' TODO: Complete member initialization 
        _p1 = p1
        _p2 = p2
    End Sub
    Sub New(p1 As String, p2 As String, p3 as String)
        ' TODO: Complete member initialization 
        _p1 = p1
        _p2 = p2
        _p3 = p3
    End Sub
End Class
```

i'd changed the SubNew-Method with 2 overloads...now u need to call the instance of the class with parameters (or without):

```
Class yyy
    Private lf As New List(Of xxx)
    Sub CallOrWhatEver()
        lf.Add(New xxx("itemdata", "name"))
        lf.Add(New xxx("p1value","p2value","p3value"))
    End Sub
End Class
```